# PHP MYSQL JSON Phonegap Login app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I was trying to make a Phonegap App which has a simple login form, which should ideally connect to a PHP form, and retrieve the user role.

I would like to clarify following things:

1. My Login Page, written in PHP works fine.
2. When given the proper credentials as Get parameters, it returns the right JSON tags :

   ```
   {"update":true,"msg":"","role":"admin"}
   ```

Here is my Phonegap App HTML code. Kindly assist me on where I am going wrong. Assume that the username is username and password is password.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <form>
        <input id="username" name="username"placeholder="Email"></input>
        <input id="password" name="password"type="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="btnLogin"/>
    </form>
<div id="myDate"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#btnLogin").click(function()
{
    $( "#myDate" ).text( "Reached Here" );
  $.ajax({
url:"https://myurl.com/api-file.php",
type:"GET",
dataType:"json",
data:{username:"username",password:"password"},
ContentType:"application/json",
success:function(response)
{
  alert(JSON.stringify(response));
},
error: function(error)
{
  alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}
})
});
});
  </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

How the App should perform is, when I click the button, it calls the jquery code, which generates an AJAx request to the php file and retrieves a JSON string, which I intend to only pop as alert, as of now.

However, clicking the button does absolutely nothing.

I am hardcoding the username and password now but can and will take it from fields later on. Need to test this first before I do that though. Kindly assist on where am I going wrong.

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/25528109/login-with-phonegap-ajax-php-and-mysql-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing is happening then the problem is with the click function, otherwise the ajax call would have displayed an error. I say try getting rid of the $(document).ready(function() and put the js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js in the head (which by the way does not have a starting tag.)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** It would help a lot if you included the errors that you are receiving, or a description of the ways that your code is not functioning as expected.

That being said, the only error I can immediately see in that code is that your `url` parameter is formatted incorrectly. Instead of this:

```
url:https:"//myurl.com/api-file.php",
```

It should be this:

```
url:"https://myurl.com/api-file.php",
```

Comment: I agree to your statement so re-editting the question. The url was wrong indeed but apparently, correcting that didn't seem to help either. Also updated the new code. Any more recommendations?